# Remove Duplicates from MySQL Table with Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have four tables (queue, songs, titles, songs_titles) that are related to each other and I need to remove duplicates that occur in the queue table.

Queue table structure is:

```
ID (primary key)
songID (foreign key from song table)
sortID
```

Titles table has structure such as:

```
ID (primary key)
title
author
lyrics
```

Songs_Titles table is structured as:

```
songID (foreign key from song table)
titlesID (foreign key from titles table)
info
```

Song table has a number of fields, but includes an ID field that is referenced in queue tables and songs_titles table.

How do I go about removing duplicate records from the queue table that have song records containing the same title?

Here's sample data return by this SQL statement from queue table.

```
SELECT * FROM queue;

ID    songID    sortID
7021    9722    8000
7018    5971    6000
7017    5953    10000
7016    10145   4000
7020    16469   14000
```

The queue table has duplicate titles that I need to remove from the table. I tried using this SQL statement. It does show duplicate title on "Zion Hears the Watchmen’s Voices" but the "Away in a Manger" is not a duplicate, but the SQL statement duplicates it in the return statement.

```
SELECT ti.title AS TitlesTableTitle, 
          q.songID AS SongsTableID, 
          q.ID AS QueueTableID
    FROM queue q
    INNER JOIN songs_titles st ON q.songID = st.songID
    INNER JOIN titles ti ON st.titlesID = ti.ID;

TitlesTableTitle                       SongsTableID   QueueTableID
Away in a Manger                        9722           7021
Away in a Manger                        9722           7021
O Come, Little Children                 9722           7021
Zion Hears the Watchmen’s Voices        5971           7018
Hush, My Dear, Lie Still and Slumber    5953           7017
Gentle Mary Laid Her Child              10145          7016
Zion Hears the Watchmen’s Voices        16469          7020
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) [mcve]

Comment: @Mech, DISTINCT is not a function. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`. Skip those extra parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply do 
`SELECT DISTINCT songID ...`.

Comment: Edited question to include some data. I don't want duplicate tracks in the queue table that have the same song title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to my problem using this SQL. It locates records in queue table that have duplicate titles and then removes the duplicate having the highest ID.

```
DELETE FROM 
  queue
WHERE 
  ID IN (
    SELECT 
      MAX(ID) 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          DISTINCT(t1.ID), 
          t1.title 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              ti.title, 
              q.songID, 
              q.ID 
            FROM 
              queue q 
              JOIN titles ti ON EXISTS (
                SELECT 
                  * 
                FROM 
                  songs_titles st 
                WHERE 
                  q.songID = st.songlistID 
                  AND st.titlesID = ti.ID
              )
          ) t1
      ) t2 
    GROUP BY 
      t2.title 
    HAVING 
      COUNT(t2.title) > 1
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqeeze the bridge-table out of the main query (you are not selecting any columns from it)

---

```
SELECT ti.title AS TitlesTableTitle 
        , q.songID AS SongsTableID
        , q.ID AS QueueTableID
 FROM queue q
 JOIN titles ti ON EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM songs_titles st
        WHERE q.songID = st.songID
        AND st.titlesID = ti.ID
        );
```